# can't update user's email

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to update the email of the current user, I went to documentation and I copied the example code that they are given there,
But nothing worked, this from doc didn't work

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

user.updateEmail("newemail@example.com").then(function() {
  console.log('success')
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log('failed')
});
```

I have also tried :

```
 try {

   await user.updateEmail('test@test.com').then(function() {
     console.log('success')           
   }).catch(function(error) {
     handleErrors(dispatch, error.message);
   });

 } catch(e) {
   handleErrors(dispatch, e.message);
 }
```

could you help to solve this issue?

update :

sorry i didn't include the exact error that come out in the console , here is the error :

> This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in
>   again before retrying this request.

2)
I should add that I am using asyncstorage of react native , and I store that Item( profile of user => email , name , ect..) in reduxPersist

that how my login code is :

```
export const login = ( email, password ) => {

        return async (dispatch) => {

            dispatch({ type: ATTEMPTING });
           try { 
            await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then(resp => handleLoginSuccess(dispatch, resp.uid,resp.name,email))
                .catch(error => handleErrorLogin(dispatch, error.message));
           }catch(e){
            handleErrorLogin(dispatch, e.message);
           }
        };

    };


  const handleLoginSuccess = async(dispatch , userId,name,email) => {

       try{
        const profile = { userId, name, email  };
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('userProfile', JSON.stringify(profile));
        dispatch({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: profile });
       }catch(e){
            alert(e.message);
       }

     }
```

Comment: Please add more information, such as what you mean by "didn't work" and any errors received. Please consider that we cannot see what you see, you need to tell us so that we can understand the issue.

Comment: Can you add the code where you login to firebase before changing the email?

Comment: Do you get anything if you do console.log(user) after var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

Comment: yes it shows data , there is user

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that there is no user logged in at the time you call `updateEmail`.  The SDK doesn't know which user you're trying to modify.  You'll need to wait until the login is fully complete before calling that method.

Note that all of the Firebase APIs are asynchronous, so you'll need to make use of their returned promises to make sure the order of calls is valid.